# Download multiple attachments

Tags: lotus-notes, attachments

The Notes native client has an option to download all attachments to a folder. 
I cannot found similiar on web based iNotes (8.5). 
Is there a way to download all attachments at once ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the full 8.5 iNotes, you can drag select multiple attachments and then click the disk icon to save them all at once.

At least in 8.5.2 iNotes, not sure about 8.5.0 or earlier versions.

Comment: It is 8.5.1 will have a look at 8.5.2. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This works with iNotes9, as you can select multiple attachments via CTRL and can then click the save-icon.

However, there will be a "save this file" dialog for every attachment seperately, at least in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Im using Lotus Notes 9. I'm able to download multiple documents as follows:-

- Instead of drag and drop, I will select all the attachments/ files in the email --> right click --> select "save all selected".

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

You can select multiple emails and select *Forward*, this will combine all attachments into one window. After that click on one of the attachments and in contextual menu select *Save All...*. However it may not work quiet well when the files have the same filename, but it depends on the operating system whether it can rename the same files.

---

When you're using specific mail provider, another way is to login to the web mail (e.g. [*Office 365*](https://login.microsoftonline.com/)) and download from there. If no option is provided, use some browser plugin to repeat the same action over and over again (like *Selenium IDE* or *TamperMonkey*).

Or forward group of e-mails with attachments to another address which is easier to access (e.g. gmail can group the attachment into single zip file, even when they've the same file names).

---

Another way is to open the inbox file format directly (*NSF format*) using alternative software (optionally you can select and archive bunch of e-mails into some specific folder, e.g. in *Actions* you can *Archive Selected Documents* into the file). On Windows, the mail files can be found in *\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data\mail*. See: [How do I find where a local Lotus Notes database is?](https://superuser.com/q/766756/87805)

Comment: not only is this question 5 years old, this response does not add anything and even contains wrong information ("Save all" is Client and NOT iNotes, OWA has nothing to do with Notes at all and using a tool does not help, if you don't have a local replica of the mail file, that you only get when you have a client...

Comment: @TorstenLink The information is correct. IBM Lotus Notes 8.5 which has option to Save All attachment when you forwarding the message. OWA is in case the company is using Microsoft provider (this was in my case). So I had problem accessing my mail attachments using Notes, but I could try to login onto web interface. Mail client saving all mails in NSF file format which is also correct.

Comment: It may be 5y old, but 8.5.2 (rev. 2011) is still installed on my corporate laptop as of 2016, so not my fault the company (widely known) is using ancient software and there is no any other way to simply download multiple attachments.