# How do I find where a local Lotus Notes database is?

Tags: lotus-notes

If I have a local (i.e. on my disk) Lotus Notes database open, how can I find which directory it's stored in? I am using Lotus Notes 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the path of database by its properties. Right click on it and go to `Application > Properties`.

Now, there can be two scenarios here.

1. If your database is stored in local `data` folder then the path would be relative to `data` folder. To find path of your `data` folder go to `File > Preferences`, under `Basic Notes Client Configuration` look for `Local application folder` which would show your `data` folder.
2. If your database is stored outside `data` folder then viewing its properties should give you the entire path.

Answer (score 0):

See in the database properties. File->Application->Properties when the db is open.
The filepath is relative to the notes data directory. Notes data directory on windows is somewhere below %appdata%\local\ibm ...